# Is it possible to have a fragment that is not in the tab bar?

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

[image]

Right now, I have five fragments (tabs) in my app as the image shows. And they are all listed as members of the tab bar in the MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements InputTab.SendMessage, FollowingTab.SendMessage, FollowerTab.SendMessage, ProfileTab.SendMessage {

    private SectionsPageAdapter pageAdapter;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    public static String currentUser;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, new ProfileTab());

        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        pageAdapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Sets up the ViewPager with the sections adapter

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager((viewPager));

    }

    // Adds fragments to SectionsPageAdapter and gives names for the corresponding tab

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        SectionsPageAdapter adapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new InputTab(), "Search");
        adapter.addFragment(new ProfileTab(), "Profile");
        adapter.addFragment(new GithubTab(), "Github Repos");
        adapter.addFragment(new FollowerTab(), "Followers");
        adapter.addFragment(new FollowingTab(), "Followings");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Since I implemented a search tab, I was wondering if it's possible to create another page(or fragment) that displays the result of the search, and when I click the result, I want to make it direct to the corresponding tabs (Profile for users, and Github Repos for repo search).

In short, how can I create a page that is not part of the tab and still display it when I press the 'search' button?

Answer (score 0):

Implement your TabLayout and ViewPager inside a fragment instead of the activiry and replace that fragment with the results fragment.

Comment: So, nothing goes inside the MainActivity?

Comment: Just a FrameLayout to contain the fragments(One with the viewpager and the results fragment).

Comment: So the MainActivity would just have a blank implementation?

Comment: Yes, except adding the viewPager fragment for the first time.

Comment: I haven't tried yet because I'm out, but just wondering if I implement my TabLayout and ViewPager inside a fragment and put MainActivity an empty page, then what should be the starting activity? Fragments cannot be starting activities

Comment: Fragments can start activities

Comment: I will try this out and give u a follow up. Thanks